# How can i create and run visual basic projects and still run in windows

Tags: application-development, monodevelop

How can i create and run visual basic projects in ubuntu.
After creating them in ubuntu would it be able to run in windows (visual studio).
If there is a way then plz suggest me and software for it.

Comment: Ubuntu is not Windows and if you want to write software to run on Windows you need Windows.  You may want to look at either dual booting or using visualisation software such as Virtualbox to run Windows but you will need a legal copy of Windows to do this.

Comment: @WarrenHill Actually it is quite possible to develop .net application on linux using Mono Develop and run them on windows. (how do I know this?) I am the develop of an opensource .net application which I developed on ubuntu using MonoDevelop and runs on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MonoDevelop to develop .net applications on linux.

If you only use libraries available cross platform then the built binaries will run on both windows and linux. Provided you are careful about new line characters(use Enviroment.NewLine) and path seperaters (use Path.Combine)

MonoDevelop does have some vb.net support, but the c# support is much better, (in some cases better then visual studio). If you are serious about cross platform .net then you should consider using c# rather then vb.net.

This is what I have done for my project Wide Margin which uses c# and runs on linux and windows.

Answer (score 0):

To run VB programs you need the MS .NET-Framework, which only runs on Windows. To use the VS IDE, you need to install WINE ([Wine](http://www.winehq.org)) and then install Visual Studio inside WINE. I cannot promise whether you will be able to use Visual Studio properly, but it's worth a try.

Comment: this is not true, Mono can be used to run vb.net applications on linux. (even ones that have been built on windows). This is possible because .net is an open EMCA standard. Visual Studo does not work on wine.

Answer (score 0):

Several BASIC *interpreters* are mentionned in a [previous thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6023/what-basic-intepreters-are-available). Those would probably handle only console-based programs.

To handle the Visual part, you may want to try [Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_(software))

Note however that Visual Basic and Visual Studio are Microsoft products and therefore genetically tied to Windows' innermost core.

To write programs that run seamlessly in both worlds, I would suggest that you jump ship altogether and give a try at Java and [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software))