# BASIC programming language

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, software-recommendation, programming

I want to run some BASIC codes on Ubuntu 14.04 . Can someone please refer to the interpreters or IDEs which are available for running BASIC codes?

Comment: You might not be old enough to remember this but, well, you're gonna have to narrow that down. There are *many* types of BASIC available so we're going to need to know which one you want before you get a very good answer. Take a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6023/what-basic-intepreters-are-available) and maybe you can find something you'd like? I'm going to flag this as a duplicate for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For classic QBASIC like compile I would recommend you FreeBASIC. It is almost completely compatible with QBASIC and also has it's own extended dialect. And it's a fully fledged compiler, your programs will run almost as fast as they were written in C. The only problem is that there is no .deb package for Ubuntu.